# Noise free EEG signal data base

Tags: eeg, data, brain-waves, signal-processing

I am working on a research paper regarding EEG signal preprocessing. The first stage includes denoising the signal. However, since I need to evaluate the performance of the method I am using, I thought of

1. Using a noise free signal
2. Add white Gaussian noise to it
3. Denoise it
4. Compare the denoised signal with the original one.

Is there a data base that contains real recordings of EEG signal ( not simulated ) and without any additive Gaussian noise. If not, is there any other way that I can use to evaluate my denoising method?

Comment: Maybe changing the title to "Evaluating EEG denoising" would help you out

Comment: The correct is to experiment different models of filters. Working with filters is surprisingly easy, in practice it's like working with multiplicative functions. The bad part is that there is usually the devices do not allow to add these filters so the signal must be transported to pc, once in pc is very easy. Finally I recommend you try out your own filter designs instead of applying the standards.